# Issue in connection pool creation using wlconfig ant task with type as JDBCConnectionPool

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am using wlconfig ant task with type as JDBCConnectionPool to setup the connection pool in weblogic. This was working till version 12.1.1. But this is failing in 12.2.1 with the below error

> Unable to create new bean with type JDBCConnectionPool, and parent
>   mbean com.bea:Name=Domain7.1,Type=Domain:missing create method:
>   javax.management.ReflectionException
>           at weblogic.utils.StackTraceDisabled.unknownMethod() Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Cannot find the method
>   createJDBCConnectionPool(java.lang.String,) for
>   com.bea:Name=Domain7.1,Type=Domain
>           ... 1 more

Ant task I am using is mentioned below

```
<target name="createConnPool">
    <wlconfig url="t3://${ip}:${port}" username="${wls.username}" password="${decryptedDomainPswd}">
        <query domain="${wls.domain}" type="Server" name="${servername}" property="medrecserver"/>
        <create type="JDBCConnectionPool" name="${db.jndiName}" property="medrecpool">
            <set attribute="CapacityIncrement" value="5"/>
            <set attribute="DriverName" value="${db.driver}"/>
            <set attribute="InitialCapacity" value="10"/>
            <set attribute="MaxCapacity" value="50"/>
            <set attribute="Password" value="${decryptedConfigDBPswd}"/>
            <set attribute="Properties" value="user=${db.userName};portNumber=${db.port};SID=${db.dbName};serverName=${db.ip}"/>
            <set attribute="RefreshMinutes" value="0"/>
            <set attribute="ShrinkPeriodMinutes" value="15"/>
            <set attribute="ShrinkingEnabled" value="true"/>
            <set attribute="URL"  value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${db.ip}:${db.port}:${db.dbName}"/>
            <set attribute="Targets" value="${medrecserver}"/>
        </create>
    </wlconfig>
</target>
```

Seems like createJDBCConnectionPool method is removed from DomainMBean from version 12.2.1 onwards. Is there any other workaround or approach for this